# Как избежать записи дубликатов в БД при использовании Entity FrameWork Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

В один момент из сторонних API наш сервис получает определённую информацию. Эту информацию нам необходимо сохранить у себя в БД. Однако возможна такая ситуация, что данные будут скачены повторно. Соответственно это либо запись новой информации с удалением старой (недопустимо в нашей ситуации), либо игнорирование дубликатов. На текущий момент для игнорирования дубликатов я вижу 2 пути:

1. Перед внесением изменений в БД взять все существующие данные, и сравнивать их. Данный подход мне не нравится тем, что нужно обрабатывать все имеющиеся записи - это означает, что будет скушано много оперативки зазря.
2. Добавлять каждую запись поштучно, затем на каждую запись вызывать `SaveChanges` - если будет встречен дубликат, то будет брошено исключение. Данный подход не нравится тем, что это займёт много времени на то, чтобы каждый раз обращаться к БД.

Есть ли в Entity FrameWork Core менее закостыленный способ решения проблемы с дубликатами?

Comment: Анатолий, а как бы Вы сделали это без EntityFramework? Допустим у Вас есть база данных и надо сделать описанное Вами с помощью запроса.

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov Я, к моему стыду, слаб в SQL, поэтому вырожу мысль как смогу: нечто вроде ``Insert Ignore <нужные данные>``. Соответственно если в момент записи такие данные уже есть, то ``Insert`` игнорируется, если нет - пишутся

Comment: Если поискать, то чаще всего находятся ответы, реализующие ваш первый способ. Даже здесь на stackoverflow десятки таких заплюсованных ответов. Но он неправильный - т. к. вставка дубликата может быть произведена другим пользователем уже после проверки.

Comment: Ваш второй способ - пожалуй, правильный. Именно так и делайте: SaveChanges - отлов исключения - в исключении содержится та Entity, которая вызвала проблему - удаляем её из контекста (детачим) - повторяем сначала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После правильно поставленного вопроса  @IgorIlyichyov в комментариях к самому вопросу, решение в некоторой степени оказалось на поверхности. Насколько я понял, в самом `Entity FrameWork Core` подходящего решения не предусмотрено. Так что как вариант - использовать SQL: (для примера взяты страны)

```
    public async Task AddCountries()
    {
         List<Country> countries = new List<Country>() {
            new Country() { Alpha2 = "AB", EnName = "Republic Of Abkhazia" },
            new Country() { Alpha2 = "AD", EnName = "Andorra" } };

        string sqlCommand = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `Countries` (`Alpha2`, `EnName`) VALUES";

        for (int i = 0; i < countries.Count; i++)
        {
            sqlCommand += $" (\"{countries[i].Alpha2}\", \"{countries[i].EnName}\")";
            if (i == countries.Count - 1)
            {
                sqlCommand += ";";
            }
            else
            {
                sqlCommand += ",";
            }
        }

        var countOfChangedStrings = await _db.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sqlCommand);
     }


public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public string Alpha2 { get; set; }
    public string EnName { get; set; }
}
```

При таком подходе нужно быть аккуратным с `SaveChanges()` - он не требуется.

**UPD:** Как верно было подмечено в комментариях, такой подход сработает с MySQL, а вот с другими СУБД - не всегда

Comment: Кстати, всегда указывайте с какой именно СУБД работаете. Судя по `insert ignore` - это MySql. Не во всех СУБД есть такая конструкция.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:
перед тем как записать в таблицу проверил бы на уникальность по какому нибудь ид.

```
.Any(x=>x.Id == entity.Id)
```

Приблизительно вот так:

```
private bool CheckIfEntityRecordExists(Entity e)
{
    var retVal = false;
    using (var db = new EntityContext())
    {
        retVal = db.Clients.Count(a => a.Id == e.Id) > 0;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: В общем случае это не работает. Проверка может выдать, что запись не существует, в этот момент другой пользователь/процесс/поток вставит в БД свою запись, тут мы вставляем запись - упс, Exception - уже дубликат.